# ERROR: Failed to parse POMs org.apache.maven.project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I was trying to build a maven project using Jenkins got the following error and the whole build failed. Maven successfully fetched from GIT code and processed.
But the POM error could not rectify. Please help me.

```
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\manoj\jenkins.war: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not P (position: START_DOCUMENT seen P... @1:1)  @ line 1, column 1
```

Comment: you might want to check the start of your pom.xml, it looks like there's something wrong there;
but without seeing the actual pom ..

Comment: C:\Users\manoj\jenkins.war is a file or a directory ? To run maven you need a pom.xml file in the directory you want to build.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque a war is a file, it's the built service

Comment: Post your Jenkins job configuration and what you are trying to do. You can't use maven to build Jenkins.war; it's already a built artifact.

Answer (score 0):

The error message alrady says it all:

```
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\manoj\jenkins.war: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not P (position: START_DOCUMENT seen P... @1:1)  @ line 1, column 1
```

So, take a look at this file...

> C:\Users\manoj\jenkins.war

The Error should be at the beginning of it...

> line 1, column 1

Comment: you are aware a war file is not a text file, right?

Comment: Oh! I didn't read the path properly! So maven tries to read the WAR-file as a POM.  No idea why this happens, sorry...